# Magento 2 : How to fix "Class Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\Interceptor does not exist"

Tags: magento2, product, category

Please help, I can't create Products or Categories. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which mode you are running Magento in, production or developer?

Comment: please explain.

Comment: I'm not sure about mode in Magento. How to see it?

Comment: Go to app -> etc -> env.php find 'MAGE_MODE' => 'mode name'.

Comment: @MichaelHa ‘default’

Comment: change it to developer and try upgrade, deploy, flush again.

Comment: @MichaelHa change ‘default’ to ‘developer’ right?

Comment: right, try this.

Comment: @MichaelHa i try it and get exception message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interceptor is not created. A coworker had this problem and we resolved it by clearing caches manually.

Try following commands in your magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

after that

```
rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/* var/cache/*
php bin/magento c:cl
php bin/magento c:fl
```